# Show that $f(x)=\log(e^{x_1}+...+e^{x_n})$ is convex

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix

> Show that the following function is convex. $$ f(x) = \log \left( e^{x_1} + \cdots + e^{x_n} \right) $$

---

I have no idea how to go about it.  I've been told to use Cauchy-Schwarz in order to show that the Hessian is non-negative definite, but I'm not sure how to do that.

The Hessian is:

- For $i \neq j$:

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} = \frac{-e^{x_i+x_j}}{\left(\sum e^{x_i}\right)^2}$$

- For $ i = j$:

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2} = \frac{e^{x_i}\sum {e^{x_i}}-e^{2x_j}}{\left(\sum e^{x_i}\right)^2}$$

After this, writing out an expression for $v^THv$ gives:

$$\sum \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2}v_i^2 + 2\sum\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_ix_j}v_iv_j$$

It's clear the first term is non-negative. I'm not sure what to do about the second term though...

Comment: You haven't really written out the formula for $v^THv$. Instead you kept the partial derivatives in there. That is obscuring the structure of the Hessian. I honestly cannot remember off the top of my head exactly what the answer is; I would have to work it out. But I know this is the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Managed to get it. Basically yes I wrote it out and then cleverly defined vectors and used Cauchy Schwarz : )

Comment: John, it looks like copper.hat did not actually use Cauchy Schwarz. If you post an answer of your own (yes, an answer to your own question) that shows what you did, I'll vote it up. I think the specific technique is illuminating in its own right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to first work with $f(x) = \log \phi(x)$. This gives
${\partial f(x) \over \partial x} = {1 \over \phi(x)} {\partial \phi(x) \over \partial x} $, and continuing, we get
${\partial^2 f(x) \over \partial x^2} = {1 \over \phi(x)^2}\left( 
\phi(x) {\partial^2 \phi(x) \over \partial x^2} - {\partial \phi(x) \over \partial x}^T {\partial \phi(x) \over \partial x} \right)$, so to verify positive semi-definiteness, we can just deal with the term in brackets, a slight simplification.

In particular, as Michael wrote in the comments, we need only verify that
$v^T \left( 
\phi(x) {\partial^2 \phi(x) \over \partial x^2} - {\partial \phi(x) \over \partial x}^T {\partial \phi(x) \over \partial x} \right) v \ge 0$.

Since $\phi(x) = \sum_i e^{x_i}$ is separable, the derivatives have a particularly easy form,
${\partial \phi(x) \over \partial x} = \begin{bmatrix}e^{x_1} & \cdots & e^{x_n} \end{bmatrix}$ and
${\partial^2 \phi(x) \over \partial x^2} = \operatorname{diag} (e^{x_1},...,e^{x_n} )$, and so we get the expression
$ \sum_i \sum_j e^{x_i} e^{x_j} ( v_j^2 - v_i v_j)$. If we swap $i,j$ and add
we get
$ \sum_i \sum_j e^{x_i} e^{x_j} ( v_j^2 - v_i v_j) = {1 \over 2} \sum_i \sum_j e^{x_i} e^{x_j} ( v_i^2+v_j^2 - 2v_i v_j)$, and since
$v_i^2+v_j^2 - 2v_i v_j = (v_i-v_j)^2 \ge 0$, we obtain the desired result.

**Note**: Here is a slightly simpler way: Show $f(y)-f(x) \ge {\partial f(x) \over \partial x}(y-x)$ instead.

Expanding, we want to show that
$\log ({ \phi(y) \over \phi(x) }) \ge { 1 \over \phi(x) }{\partial \phi(x) \over \partial x}(y-x)$, which is the same as showing
$\log ( { \sum_k e^{y_k} \over \sum_k e^{x_k} } ) = \log ( \sum_k { e^{x_k} \over \sum_i e^{x_i} } e^{y_k-x_k}) 
\ge  \sum_k { e^{x_k} \over \sum_i e^{x_i} } (y_k-x_k)$.

Let $\mu_k = { e^{x_k} \over \sum_i e^{x_i} } $ and notice that these are convex multipliers, so we want to show
$\log ( \sum_k \mu_k e^{y_k-x_k}) 
\ge  \sum_k \mu_k (y_k-x_k)$, which follows since $\log$ is concave.